# Clustering of sequential data

Tags: clustering

Given the following scenario, I have a really long street. Each house on the street has some number of children. If I were to sequentially append the number of children in each house along an array, I could get some array like:

```
x = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
```

I want to locationally determine areas where the households cluster, i.e. I want to group the 2's together, the 3's together, and the 2's at the end together. Normally on 1D data I would sort, determine difference, and find clusters of 1, 2, and 3. But here, I want to keep the index of these values as a factor. So I wanto to end up identifying clusters as:

```
index: value
0-4 :  1
5-8:   2
9-12:  1
13-16: 3
17-20: 1
21-24: 2
```

I have seen mean shift used for this detection, and would like to implement this in python. I have also seen kernal density functions. Does anyone know how best to implement this in python?

Comment: It seems like a programming question. You should be able to get a quick answer at stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

That is a one-liner.

Don't look for an "algorithm", just write it yourself.

Simple approach: use a for loop, compare to the previous value...